# Raphael.js World Map: How to make it scalable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

In my new web app I am using Raphael.js to render an SVG map.  I am having a hard time making it scalable though.  Is it possible to make this scalable since I believe the world.js file associated with this maps out specific sizes for the map? http://raphaeljs.com/world/

```
var w = $("#trek_map").width(),
h = $("#trek_map").height();

Raphael("trek_map",
w,
h,
function() {
    var r = this;

    r.setStart();

    var hue = Math.random();

    for (var country in worldmap.shapes) {
        r.path(worldmap.shapes[country]).attr({
            stroke: "#fff",
            fill: "#868e99",
            "stroke-opacity": 0.6
        });
    }

    var world = r.setFinish();
});
```

Comment: I suspect it may help to post a fiddle highlighting the problem, so that people can play around with it.

Comment: Could you explain more for what does your 'scalable' means?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the viewbox property as this plugin does: https://github.com/escobar5/raphael-pan-zoom